# Update Mono via CentOS

Tags: mono, centos

Hello i have CentOS and im trying my damnedest to update Mono i have version 1.2.4 at the moment some how, and im trying to compile something via xbuild and it isn't working im thinking because im using to old a version of mono.

Please BEFORE you link me ANY guide, if it links to the ftp.novell directory it no longer works, that directory is all scrapped. So i dont even know where to get a proper tarball for it now because on their site it only shows opensuse and such? Not CentOS like there used to be.

Can anyone help me with this :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of CentOS are you using? 4?

The instructions below were tested on CentOS 5.9. They will also work fine on the latest CentOS version (6.4 as of this writing) and I imagine they would work with older versions as well.

Head over to `/usr/src` as root

```
su
cd /usr/src
```

Ensure GCC and friends are installed (to build the Mono source code)

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ bison
```

Grab and unpack the Mono source code

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.0.7.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf mono-3.0.7.tar.bz2
```

Build and install Mono

```
cd mono-3.0.7
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Verify that you have a working Mono installation with `mono --version` and `mcs --version`

Build the GDI+ compatibility layer (required for System.Drawing)

```
yum install glib2-devel libX11-devel pixman-devel fontconfig-devel freetype-devel libexif-devel libjpeg-devel glib2-devel libtif-devel libpng-devel giflib-devel

cd /usr/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf libgdiplus-2.10.tar.bz2
```